# Green bubble SMS not working on strong WiFi with weak cell signal, iPhone 13 + Verizon

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, sms

I'm using iPhone 13 with iOS 16.3.1 and Verizon Wireless.

In my office, the WiFi signal is very strong, but cell signal is weak, i.e. between 0 and 1 bar most of the time.

From some googling, I understand that if I have "WiFi calling" turned on, it's supposed to use WiFi to send green bubble SMS too. However, instead the green bubble messages I send are very flaky, i.e. they only get delivered like 1/3 of the time, and the other 2/3 of the time there's a red (!) icon next to the green bubble, which says "not deliver"; I have to constantly toggle Airplane mode on and off to get the cell bars higher and then sometimes it works.

In contrast, blue bubble iMessages work fine. Also, when I'm outside on the street and I have five bars with 5G, green bubble SMS also work fine.

Am I doing something wrong in the "weak cell strong WiFi" case? Isn't turning on "WiFi calling" supposed to make sending green bubble SMS texts just as quick and snappy since I'm on a strong WiFi connection?

EDIT: I also tried turning on airplane mode with wifi manually turned on, and was able to browse Safari, but SMS still didn't work; this time instantly went to "failed to send" instead of struggling a bit.

Comment: Force your phone to use only WiFi by turning off cellular.  If you have a signal, even a weak one, it will try SMS first and not necessarily fall back to WiFi.

Comment: You can turn off cellular in Control Center by pressing the green button with an antenna icon.  I’ve done this before and it worked. How did SMS instantly fail?  What message did it give you?

Comment: SMS does not use cellular data; MMS does. So turning it off as you describe has no effect.  Verizon might be preventing messages being blocked that don’t originate on their network.  Check with them fir details.

Comment: (deleted all my previous comments) TLDR: tried airplane mode with wifi on, toggling green antenna button, none of which work. If Verizon really prevents all SMS that don't originate from their network, and my wifi router obvious does not count as Verizon network, then by definition SMS by wifi doesn't works. Have you confirmed that SMS works for you? i.e. when you're in a very weak cell signal but strong wifi signal area, you can very easily send SMS?

Comment: I sent a message to an Android user today with Cellular off and it went through. I use AT&T

Comment: was it SMS or MMS? I don't care about MMS, I'm just trying to send SMS. If SMS doesn't use cellular data, and the green cellular icon simply turns off cellular data, then that icon will have no effect on SMS. Are you able to do the same in an area with zero bars?

Comment: It was SMS.  The green button in CC turns off **all** cellular, not just data .  I have full strength everywhere, but when you turn off cellular, it becomes  a moot point.

Comment: I doubt the validity of the last comment: I tried the green button again, and I still cannot send SMS in a location with strong wifi (my office building in NYC). In addition, the upper-right corner of the screen still shows 1 bar. If it turned off all cellular, wouldn't there be a "cross out" icon? Also, I don't think it's moot in your case; if I'm correct that the button only turns off data, then your SMS is working because of your full strength, not because it's using Wifi. Does it still show 5 bars for you when you turn off the green button? I think yes?

Comment: see from this [apple discussion forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8114697), where an apple-recommended answer says that the green button means "cellular data on", not "all cellular on"!

Comment: Then put it in airplane mode

Comment: good idea, but that didn't work either. I had wifi manually turned on with airplane mode but still could not send SMS; it failed instantly

Comment: Then Verizon blocks it